# SQL visual studio command

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2013

i am trying to update a mysql database through visual studio

```
String str = "server=localhost;database=population;username=root;password=hello;Convert Zero Datetime=true;";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(str);
        string col1 = col.Text;
        string newval1=newval.Text;
        string val1=val.Text;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string cmdstr="update npanxx set \""+col1+"\" = \""+newval1+"\" where NPA_NXX=\""+val1+"\"";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
        }
```

when I run this and click the button it says I have a syntax error but I have not be able to find it. Can anyone point it out to me

Comment: You code is vulnerable to a [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. You should use bind parameters. Your syntax error will most likely go away, too.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using single quotes?

Comment: @nvoigt this code is just for learning purposes but how would I go about using bind parameters

Comment: MySQL does not follow the ANSI SQL standard for quoting. MySQL’s default quoting behavior is that either single or double quotes can be used to quote a string

Comment: @juharr I tried single quotes I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

You don't need quotes around the column col1:

```
String str = "server=localhost;database=population;username=root;password=hello;Convert Zero Datetime=true;";
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(str);
    string col1 = col.Text;
    string newval1=newval.Text;
    string val1=val.Text;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string cmdstr="update npanxx set "+col1+" = \""+newval1+"\" where NPA_NXX=\""+val1+"\"";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: What if the column name has a space in it?  You'd use square brackets for SQL Server, but MySql using quotes in that case, or maybe back ticks or single quotes.  It's not very obvious based on a quick google search.

Comment: MySQL uses back ticks for column or table names with a space, for example: SELECT * FROM `Table One`

Answer (score -1):

I would do it this way:

```
String str = "server=localhost;database=population;username=root;password=hello;Convert Zero Datetime=true;";
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(str);
    string col1 = col.Text;
    string newval1=newval.Text;
    string val1=val.Text;
          try
          {
          con.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Update npanxx set '"+ col1 +"'='" + newval1 + "' WHERE NPA_NXX= '" + val1 + "'", con);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, con);
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           con.Close();

          }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how this improves the previous answer + you seem to have a bad copy&paste.. where is `cmdstr` initialized ? Assuming the second `new MySqlCommand...` is a bad c&p, you basically suggest not creating a temporary String variable